# Of Healthy Programming Practices

Tags: python, function, math, module

I need advice. I'm writing a calculator; I've got the basic functionality of it down, and have finally moved to having it process functions. In this regard, I find the standard library of mathematical functions provided by Python unsatisfactory.

While the more commonly used functions are defined, some of the more obscure functions lack proper mention. Examples of this include the arc hyperbolic cotangent, arc hyperbolic cosecant, hyperbolic cosecant, secant, etc. While some of these are just manipulations of the functions provided, it seems the better alternative would be to provide our definitions and refer the program to those when it encounters them.

This is where my question lies. Should I just define these functions in the main script, or should I use a separate file? If I the latter, how do I make reference to the separate file? I am relatively new to Python, so if I'm missing a common technique or something, please do let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [numpy hyperbolic functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.math.html#hyperbolic-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I just define these functions in the main script, or should I use a separate file? If I the latter, how do I make reference to the separate file? I am relatively new to Python, so if I'm missing a common technique or something, please do let me know. Thanks in advance.

The `import` statement is an important part of python:

Put your functions in a separate file, say `mymath.py`:

```
def foo(x):
    # Code goes here
```

Then import your module:

```
import mymath
print(mymath.foo(y))
```

Comment: Does the file mymath.py have to be in the same directory as the calculator? What if I want to import mymath.py from elsewhere? Is there some place where it can be accessed "globally?"

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId You neither need nor want it to pester every other script on the whole system. Create a package, e.g. with [disutils](http://docs.python.org/py3k/distutils/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would make a small math utility module like you suggest. Simply create `advmath.py` with

```
def csch(z):
    "Hyperbolic cosecant"
    return 1 / sinh(z)

def sinh(z):
    "Hyperbolic sine"
    ...
```

and then you can [import](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) this module in your main script:

```
import advmath
```

You now have access to functions and variables defines in the module:

```
advmath.csch(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get the numpy and scipy libraries which include many of these functions for you.

> Should I just define these functions in the main script, or should I
>   use a separate file?

It depends on how complicated your calculator is. But it probably should go in a separate file.

> If I the latter, how do I make reference to the separate file?

Use import. `import foo` will try to load the file `foo.py`. Then you access the functions inside foo as `foo.function_name`. You should be able to find a lot of questions about using it on this site.

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time with the excellent tutorial regarding [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) on the python site.

In general, yes. If you have components that you want to reuse, these are best kept in separate module files.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def fib(n):    # write Fibonacci series up to n
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
        print b,
        a, b = b, a+b
                    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "testing fib(10)"
    fib(10)
```

Place that code in a seperate file called `fib.py` in a known directory -- say your personal bin folder. Run the python interactive shell from that directory.

Now:

```
>>> import fib
>>> fib.fib(10)
1 1 2 3 5 8
```

With this method you can build up a personally library of functions that is readily available to you.

Note the code here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "testing fib(10)"
    fib(10)
```

That allows you to place a test harness and the end of your modules that will execute if the module is executed other than as a library import.

Much of this may not be necessary however. The excellent [numpy](https://numpy.org/) and [scipy](https://scipy.org/) probably have every math function that you can dream of.